# How to use encodeAsHTML() for blank value?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

when i using encodeAsHTML() for a textbox in blank value .. it shows me **null** value in textbox rather than **blank**  value

how to display a blank textbox using encodeAsHTML()

```
<input type="text" value="${params.loc.encodeAsHTML()}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="${params.loc?.encodeAsHTML()}" />
```

through **?.encodeAsHTML()**  this we can display a blank textbox rather than null value textbox